# Select a hyperlink in one column based on "X" in adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

So I'm fairly new to VBA, and I have been struggling with trying to get my macro to work.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a program read down a column, and for every "X" located in that column, the corresponding hyperlink in the adjacent column will be selected.

```
Sub Select_Hyperlinks()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, sel As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For x = 1 To 6
    Set sht = Sheets("Generator")
    Set sel = cell.Offset(-1, 0)

    Set rng = Intersect(sht.Range("D4:D9"), sht.UsedRange)
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If (cell.Value) <> "X" _
        Then
            If sel Is Nothing Then
            Set sel = cell.Offset(-1, 0)
            sel.Select
        End If
        Next cell
    End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

I also tried a simpler idea using the Find and FindNext functions and for each X, I tried to get it to select and activate the cell in the adjacent column, but also with no luck. It seems I always get snagged up on the .Offset function.

EDIT:

Here's what I've managed to come up with, after some further research. I've adapted this from a macro designed to delete all empty rows.

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Dim xlastcell As Integer
Dim xcell As Integer
xcell = 1

Range("C200").End(xlUp).Select
xlastcell = ActiveCell.Cells   'This used to say ActiveCell.Row but I want a single cell'


Do Until xcell = xlastcell

    If Cells(xcell, 1).Value = "X" Then
    Cells(x, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select   'I'm also unable to get this function to work'
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

    xcell = xcell - 1
    xlastcell = xlastcell - 1

    End If

xcell = xcell + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Did your new code solve your problem? The code I posted in my edit below does in fact work, you will just need to change the range to match your range.

Comment: That works perfectly, and is much more elegant than what I was trying to do. Now to see if I can get it to cycle through multiple sheets! Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to do the same thing on each sheet?

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work though. Your code was very easily translated into what I needed it to do. Now another quesiton would be, can I use this code to select embedded objects instead of hyperlinks?

Comment: They are embedded in the cell similar to a hyperlink? What type of object specifically?

Comment: Well I have a list of Word documents that open up with the click of a button. Currently all of the separate files are stored in a folder and the macro selects the hyperlinks to those files. But I'd like to embed them all into this single excel file, as opposed to having to send people hundreds of files stored in multiple folders.

Comment: Do you want the embedded objects to be linked to the Word docs? Will it always be the same docs, or do you need it to select which document dynamically? If it is the same documents, you can create document links that will update with any changes to the Word doc automatically. Otherwise, you would have to loop through the files to embed and create the object.

Comment: I managed to find my answer, it appears that there's no real way to create a macro in excel that would call upon an embedded object in a column the same way I was trying to do it with the hyperlinks. So for now, I think that's all the help I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that if there is an X in the one column, you want to open the hyperlink?

EDIT:
Use this and change things to match your variables.

```
Sub asdhkl()
Dim c As Hyperlink
Dim i As Range
For Each i In Sheets(1).Range("b1:b3")
    If i = "x" Then
        Set c = i.Offset(0, -1).Hyperlinks(1)
        c.Follow
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Right, but the hyperlink is located in a different column. I've been looking more into VBA and feel like I've got a code that should do what I want, but I'm still unfamiliar with some of the language and syntax.